# Why are erlang lib changes not being incorporated into my project?

Tags: erlang, rebuild, binaries, erl, beam

I'm using eclipse 3.6.2 with erlang 5.8.1.1 on a fairly large project that we're not ready to move to a more modern version of the language, so I'm stuck with a bug in eprof:

```
string_bp_mfa([{Mfa, {Count, Time}}|Mfas], Tus, {MfaW, CountW, PercW, TimeW, TpCW}, Strings) ->
    Smfa   = s(Mfa),
    Scount = s(Count),
    Stime  = s(Time),
    Sperc  = s("~.2f", [100*(Time/Tus)]),
    Stpc   = s("~.2f", [Time/Count]),

    string_bp_mfa(Mfas, Tus, {
        erlang:max(MfaW,  length(Smfa)),
        erlang:max(CountW,length(Scount)),
        erlang:max(PercW, length(Sperc)),
        erlang:max(TimeW, length(Stime)),
        erlang:max(TpCW,  length(Stpc))
        }, [[Smfa, Scount, Sperc, Stime, Stpc] | Strings]).
```

Which crashes for me all the time because whoever wrote this didn't guard against dividebyzero.  I've hacked in a change:

```
SafeTus = case Tus of 0 -> 1; _ -> Tus end,
SafeCount = case Count of 0 -> 1; _ -> Count end,
Sperc  = s("~.2f", [100*(Time/SafeTus)]),
Stpc   = s("~.2f", [Time/SafeCount]),
```

...but it is never executed by my project.  I've manually recompiled the .erl and placed the .beam in the ebin directory, but after a total shutdown of my project, closing eclipse, opening eclipse, refreshing, cleaning, and restarting, the new version of the method is not executed.  I've tried sticking expressions like "foo + 1" into the method to see if I get a different exception than the badarith that is taking me down now, but to no effect.

I can only guess that the .beams are being consolidated or cached somewhere that I'm going to have to nuke or rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for [`code`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html) module, which explains code path search. Since `eprof` is in the `tools` application, it should be picked up from any additional library directories.